# How to remove the empty space from TabView using page style in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, ios17

I have a `NavigationStack` where I have a `TabView` and its style as page style and a `List` after the `TabView`.

Inside the `TabView` I have another custom view that has a horizontal `List` and I want to remove the space between the the inner child and the parent.

I tried with `padding`, plain list style but the space is still there.

I can use `frame` modifier but I don't want a hard coded value for the height.

Here is the code I tried:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomView: View {
    var dataArray: [String]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(dataArray, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button("\(item)") {
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                }
            }
        
        }
        .scrollDisabled(true)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    struct Sea: Hashable, Identifiable {
        let name: String
        let id = UUID()
    }

    struct OceanRegion: Identifiable {
        let name: String
        let seas: [Sea]
        let id = UUID()
    }

    private let oceanRegions: [OceanRegion] = [
        OceanRegion(name: "Pacific",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Australasian Mediterranean"),
                           Sea(name: "Philippine"),
                           Sea(name: "Coral"),
                           Sea(name: "South China")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Atlantic",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "American Mediterranean"),
                           Sea(name: "Sargasso"),
                           Sea(name: "Caribbean")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Indian",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Bay of Bengal")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Southern",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Weddell")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Arctic",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Greenland")])
    ]

    @State private var singleSelection: UUID?

    @State private var weekIndex = 0
    @State private var weeks = [ -1, 0, 1 ]

    @State private var dataArray1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    @State private var dataArray2 = ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14"]
    @State private var dataArray3 = ["15","16","17","18","19","20","21"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                TabView(selection: $weekIndex) {
                    CustomView(dataArray: dataArray1).tag(weeks[0])
                    CustomView(dataArray: dataArray2).tag(weeks[1])
                    CustomView(dataArray: dataArray3).tag(weeks[2])
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .indexViewStyle(.page(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
            }
                
            List(selection: $singleSelection) {
                ForEach(oceanRegions) { region in
                    Section(header: Text("Major \(region.name) Ocean Seas")) {
                        ForEach(region.seas) { sea in
                            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                                Text(sea.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Oceans and Seas")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to remove that empty space?

How can I expand the list inside the tab view to take all the width and zero padding at the top?

How can I set `TabView`'s height dynamically, to take its child height?

Comment: A TabView should not be inside a NavigationStack, each tab needs its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Benzy mentioned the `TabView` used inside `NavigationStack` is not recommended so I finaally found an alternative that works really well.

I used `ScrollViewReader` and `ScrollView(.horizontal)`  together with some modifiers like `.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)`, `.scrollTargetLayout()` and `.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)`. Other modifiers can be used to get the scroll position for example.

It is taking the minimum space and is swipeable.

The `ScrollViewReader` is not entirely necessary if the start is at index 0 but if the initial display is not index 0 then it is necessary to preset to which index to `scrollTo`. Also this can be controlled using a button for example.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomView: View {
    var dataArray: [String]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(dataArray, id: \.self) { item in
                Button("\(item)") {
                    print("\(item)")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    struct Sea: Hashable, Identifiable {
        let name: String
        let id = UUID()
    }

    struct OceanRegion: Identifiable {
        let name: String
        let seas: [Sea]
        let id = UUID()
    }

    private let oceanRegions: [OceanRegion] = [
        OceanRegion(name: "Pacific",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Australasian Mediterranean"),
                           Sea(name: "Philippine"),
                           Sea(name: "Coral"),
                           Sea(name: "South China")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Atlantic",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "American Mediterranean"),
                           Sea(name: "Sargasso"),
                           Sea(name: "Caribbean")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Indian",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Bay of Bengal")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Southern",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Weddell")]),
        OceanRegion(name: "Arctic",
                    seas: [Sea(name: "Greenland")])
    ]

    @State private var singleSelection: UUID?

    @State private var weekIndex: Int?
    @State private var weeks = [ -1, 0, 1 ]

    @State private var dataArray1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
    @State private var dataArray2 = ["8","9","10","11","12","13","14"]
    @State private var dataArray3 = ["15","16","17","18","19","20","21"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack {
                        CustomView(dataArray: dataArray1)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .id(weeks[0])
                        CustomView(dataArray: dataArray2)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .id(weeks[1])
                        CustomView(dataArray: dataArray3)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .id(weeks[2])
                    }
                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                }
                .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .onAppear {
                    value.scrollTo(weeks[1])
                }
                .scrollPosition(id: $weekIndex)
            }
        
            List(selection: $singleSelection) {
                ForEach(oceanRegions) { region in
                    Section(header: Text("Major \(region.name) Ocean Seas")) {
                        ForEach(region.seas) { sea in
                            NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
                                Text(sea.name)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
            .navigationTitle("Oceans and Seas")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for the gaps can be explained as follows:

- The small space at the top is because each `CustomView` contains a `List` and the default list style is `.insetGrouped`. This list style comes with padding above, below and at the sides.
- The big space in the middle is because `TabView` and `List` are both greedy, so they want to use as much space as possible. Consequently, they are both given 50% of the available height.

Regarding the `TabView`, you are using a paged view style, but the index indicators have been disabled. So I am wondering why you are using a `TabView` at all? If the only reason is to allow a change of `weekIndex` using swipe then you might want to consider a simpler container and perhaps an alternative navigation mechanism. In any case, a `Tabview` should normally be the parent for a `NavigationStack` and not the other way around (as also mentioned in the comment by *lorem ipsum*).

I would suggest the following changes to resolve the spacing issues:

- Replace the `TabView` with a simpler (non-greedy) container such as a `ZStack`.
- Remove the `List` and `LazyHStack` (both of which are greedy) from `CustomView`. Just use a simple `HStack` and apply your own padding as required.
- Implement your own way of navigating between groups of weeks. A simple solution would be to use buttons for selecting the previous/next group.
- It might also be an idea to show a title above the week numbers.

These changes are illustrated below:

```swift
struct CustomView: View {
    var dataArray: [String]

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(dataArray, id: \.self) { item in
                // content as before
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    // other content as before

    private var prevNextButtons: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Previous") {
                weekIndex = max(weekIndex - 1, weeks.first ?? 0)
            }
            .opacity(weekIndex == weeks.first ? 0 : 1)

            Spacer()

            Button("Next") {
                weekIndex = min(weekIndex + 1, weeks.last ?? 0)
            }
            .opacity(weekIndex == weeks.last ? 0 : 1)
        }
        .overlay {
            Text("Weeks")
                .font(.headline)
        }
    }

    private var weekGroup: some View {
        ZStack {
            if weekIndex == weeks[0] {
                CustomView(dataArray: dataArray1)
            } else if weekIndex == weeks[1] {
                CustomView(dataArray: dataArray2)
            } else {
                CustomView(dataArray: dataArray3)
            }
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 6)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background {
            Color(UIColor.secondarySystemGroupedBackground)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                VStack {
                    prevNextButtons
                    weekGroup
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemGroupedBackground))

                List(selection: $singleSelection) {
                    // content as before
                }
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: weekIndex)
            .navigationTitle("Oceans and Seas")
            .toolbar {
                // content as before
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand now how `NavigationStack` works. If I add another `List` at the end then all 3 containers height will be 1/3 of the screen height. I will try your solution and maybe implement some swiping for the weekGroup rather than buttons.